# how does webpack solve global polution?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, namespaces

Let's say I have 3 functions. If I write them all one by one, below each other, all of them will be exposed to the global namespace hence global polution. So one way seems to be the following.

```
var test;
(function() {

 test.funct1 = function(){

 }

 test.funct2 = function(){

 }

 test.funct3 = function(){

 }

})
```

Now, we reduced the problem since the functions are not put into the global namespace. We could say, they still are, but not completely. `test` will be put on the global `namespace` which would have all other functions on it.

Question 1) Now, the problem still exists, if someone or some library has `test`  , the problem is my `test` and the library's `test` will be collided, which seems too bad. How do people solve this without any library/framework or whatever (without webpack) ?

Question 2) Okay, so webpack does solve the above problem. In webpack, each file is the module. That's understandable, but still, a good nice example would be great, some stuff still have to be put on global scope. I'd appreciate a good nice example.

Comment: Please try to ask only one question in a question

Comment: They are almost related and seems better to ask it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the problem still exists, if someone or some library has test , the problem is my test and the library's test will be collided, which seems too bad. How do people solve this without any library/framework or whatever (without webpack) ?

Declare the `test` only inside the scope where it's necessary; don't make it global. For example, you could have:

```
<script>

(() => {
  const test = {
    funct1() {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  };
  // do stuff with test
})();

(() => {
  const test = {
    OTHER_METHOD() {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  };
  // do stuff with test
})();

</script>
```

This way, neither `test` is global; they're both enclosed in their own IIFE, and all uses of a particular `test` will be inside that IIFE.

> some stuff still have to be put on global scope

The whole point of a module system like Webpack is to *avoid having to pollute* the global object; if your code is structured reasonably, there shouldn't be any need for it. But if you *had* to, just refer to the global object and assign to one of its properties, eg:

```
// someModule.js
window.SomethingGlobal = {
  // stuff
};
```

This isn't particular to Webpack; this same exact approach for reducing global pollution is available ES6 modules

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If webpack doesn't put anything on global object, how can this be possible ? Let's say I am using Vue. It's still not on global scope. Where is this ? Vue object still has to be global since it gets used in the whole application

Comment: Imagine any script you can think of. Then put its whole contents into an IIFE. Then, nothing in that script will be global! (unless it's done somewhere explicitly with `window.someprop = someval`) IIFEs prevent implicit global pollution.

Comment: It makes sense what you're saying.