# JavaScript: Unable to access module's variable from chrome's console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to access some variables (of script.js) on chrome's console. I'm able to do so only until I turn my script.js into a module (type="module") in index.html. If i try to access any variable when i have type=module on my script tag, i get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: *variable_name* is not defined
> at <anonymous>:1:1

```
<script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045 A module is like an IIFE; nothing defined inside the module is visible globally unless you explicitly do something like `window.someVar = 'foo'`, so the console can't see it

Comment: is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See my comment - *unless you explicitly do something like `window.someVar = 'foo'`*

Comment: unfortunately, i just removed type=module, and bundled everything using webpack, but still getting the error

Comment: Webpack also runs all of its bundled code inside an IIFE https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691996 nearly the same way ES6 modules work.

Comment: thanks my dumb brain couldn't think that variables might be scoped within the webpack's output file